# Serialization format for small data and large schema

Tags: java, c++, json, serialization, avro

I am working on an application where we need to send some data from the client and also from server to client. The client is in C++ and the server is in Java. The data is going to be real time and in micro-batches; so, performance is our main concern. We were looking into Avro as the serialization format. The problem is our data is going to be very small but the schema will be large enough. Avro sends the schema every time it sends the data. This would make our datafile large, unnecessarily.

The questions are:

1.) Is it possible in Avro to send only the data and the schema version? And, store the schema in client and server separately.

2.) Is there any other data serialization technique that I should consider here, instead of Avro?

3.) Will the plain JSON format and then compressing it will be more compact than  the Avro format for this particular use case?

Comment: Try `google protocol buffers` (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/). Small pockets, no schema to send. Very fast.